# What is bzr for cvs export?

Tags: export, cvs, bazaar

With cvs one can export the files that have a specific tag and get no cvs meta data included such as with this command:

```
cvs -z3 -d:ext:cwhii@emle.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/emle export -R -r BL0123 -d emle030205_BL0123 emle
```

What is the corresponding bzr command where the [launchpad.net](http://launchpad.net) branch is `lp:emle` and the tag is `BL0123`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bzr export -r tag:BL0123 DEST lp:emle
```

See the help for `bzr export` command.